# By Using DataFrame's and 'where()' method which selects rows where A is greater than 5 or B is greater than 5

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Given a Spark DataFrame in a variable `t` representing a table with two integer columns (A, B) , write the expression using DataFrame columns to be passed as parameter of the DataFrame's `where()` method which selects rows where A is greater than 5 or B is greater than 5. Using the DataFrame variable and not use by the `col()` function.

Comment: why would one not use the `col()` function?

Comment: Nope my professor wana only DataFrame no Col ()

Comment: Is somebody help me here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `col` functions: one from the [Dataset class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@col(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and  one from [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@col(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column). In this simple case, both would work:

```scala
t.where(t.col("A").gt(5).or(t.col("B").gt(5))).show() //from dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
t.where(col("A").gt(5).or(col("B").gt(5))).show() //from functions
```

Depending which of the two you want to avoid, you can take the other one.

If you use Scala, also `$` works:

```scala
t.where($"A">5 or $"B">5).show
```

You can also switch entirely to the sql syntax:

```scala
t.where("A > 5 or B > 5").show
```

If `filter` is allowed, the lamdba version would also work:

```scala
t.filter(r => r.getInt(0) > 5 || r.getInt(1) > 5).show
```